# decrease image resolution = increase distance between object camera?

Tags: image-processing, distance, resolution, object-detection

I was wondering if I scale an image, reducing its dimensions by half using python `cv2.resize` (lets say, from 600x600 to 300x300) and then I rescale it back up to its original dimension (300x300 to 600x600) thus, lowering its resolution... that is equivalent to physically increasing the distance between the camera and an object?

If the above is true, is there a relationship that estimate this increment in distance given a certain decrement in the image resolution?

Im tracking an object in a set of high resolution images and I want to know, given the same conditions, if I can track the same object from a higher distance.

Thank you

Comment: this question does not fit to SO in my opinion

Comment: that depends on your camera and optics. but in most cases increasing distance will decrease object resolution.